# String binding error

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, binding

Why can't I create a simple WPF string data binding in my class?

> *Error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.*

I've followed [this example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
Dim s As String = "Test string"
Dim b As New Binding("Description of bind")
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneTime
b.Source = s
```

Comment: Are you aware that you ought to pass a binding `Path` to the constructor, not any textual description of the binding?

Comment: thankyou for comment, but what you mean? can you give me an example please?

Comment: I was pointing out to you that `"Description of bind"` is most likely not a valid argument to the [`Binding` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578.aspx) which you are calling. The constructor does not take in *any* textual (human-language) description of the binding's nature; it expects a binding `Path`, which has a specific syntax which you must observe; e.g. `"/Offices/ManagerName"` or `"ShoppingCart.Order"`. [See the documentation of `Binding.Path` for details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VB but it would appear the line should read:

```
Dim b As New Binding()
b.Path = New PropertyPath("Description of bind")
```

I referred to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838207%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-9).